# gsutil parallel deletion on empty buckets

Tags: google-cloud-storage

We're getting errors when trying to run `gsutil -m rm -r gs://bucketname` if the bucket itself is empty:

```
$ gsutil -m rm -r gs://scoletestbucket
Removing gs://scoletestbucket/...
CommandException: 1 files/objects could not be removed.
$ echo $?
1
```

Despite the error message, though, the command does exactly what we want it to do: it removes the bucket. But our scripting that's monitoring command return codes naturally thinks the gsutil command is reporting an error.

Everything works as expected if we leave off the parallelism option (`-m`), but we'd kind of like to keep it if possible, for the situations when we're actually deleting bunches of stuff.

Are we missing something, or is this a bug?

Comment: This is a bug in the gsutil rm command.  I've opened https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/319 to track it.